# insert data to table called game

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to insert data to table called game but getting the following error:
you have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server

This is the C# code:

```
   int i = 0;
   MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
   string command = string.Format("insert into game (HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR,HTHG,HTAG,HTR,HS,AS,HST,AST,HF,AF,HC,AC,HY,AY,HR,AR,DIV) VALUES(@HomeTeam,@AwayTeam,@FTHG,@FTAG,@FTR,@HTHG,@HTAG,@HTR,@HS,@AS,@HST,@AST,@HF,@AF,@HC,@AC,@HY,@AY,@HR,@AR,@DIV)");
   cmd.CommandText = command;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeTeam", _games[i].HomeTeam.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AwayTeam", _games[i].AwayTeam.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FTHG", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].FTHG));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FTAG", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].FTAG)); ;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FTR", _games[i].FTR.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HTHG", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].HTHG));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HTAG", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].HTAG));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HTR", _games[i].HTR.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HS", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].HS));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AS", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].AS));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HST", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].HST));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AST", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].AST));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HF", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].HF));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AF", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].AF));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HC", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].HC));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AC", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].AC));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HY", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].HY));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AY", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].AY));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HR", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].HR));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AR", Convert.ToInt32(_games[i].AR));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIV", _games[i].DIV.ToString());
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

HomeTeam, AwayTeam, DIV, FTR, HTR are varchars all the rst are int's.
At the list all the fields are strings.

Cn someone see any error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "AS" and "DIV" keywords at column names.
Escape them with **`**

try this:

```
insert into game (HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR,HTHG,HTAG,HTR,HS,`AS`,HST,AST,HF,AF,HC,AC,HY,AY,HR,AR,`DIV`) VALUES(@HomeTeam,@AwayTeam,@FTHG,@FTAG,@FTR,@HTHG,@HTAG,@HTR,@HS,@AS,@HST,@AST,@HF,@AF,@HC,@AC,@HY,@AY,@HR,@AR,@DIV);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used a reserved word `AS` , `DIV` as column name and you need to backtick it within the query.

```
insert into game 
(HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR,HTHG,HTAG,HTR,HS,`AS`,HST,AST,.....
```

Check the reserved words list here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: i've chaned it to :

        string command = string.Format("insert into game ('HomeTeam','AwayTeam','FTHG','FTAG','FTR','HTHG','HTAG','HTR',HS,'AS','HST','AST','HF','AF','HC','AC','HY','AY','HR','AR','DIV') VALUES(@HomeTeam,@AwayTeam,@FTHG,@FTAG,@FTR,@HTHG,@HTAG,@HTR,@HS,@AS,@HST,@AST,@HF,@AF,@HC,@AC,@HY,@AY,@HR,@AR,@DIV)");

and still the same issue...

Comment: Make sure to add backtick for `div` as well. Check the reserved keyword list.

Comment: No single quote its ` `

Comment: i;ve done it but still it not working:

            string command = string.Format("insert into game (`HomeTeam`,`AwayTeam`,`FTHG`,`FTAG`,`FTR`,`HTHG`,`HTAG`,`HTR`,`HS`,`AS,`HST`,`AST`,`HF`,`AF`,`HC`,`AC`,`HY`,`AY`,`HR`,`AR`,`DIV`) VALUES(@HomeTeam,@AwayTeam,@FTHG,@FTAG,@FTR,@HTHG,@HTAG,@HTR,@HS,@AS1,@HST,@AST,@HF,@AF,@HC,@AC,@HY,@AY,@HR,@AR,@DIV1)");

Answer (score 0):

Is hometeam and awayteam classified as classes here? 
If so, try to pass just the hometeam.teamname into the database.